# No ocultar EditText con teclado

Tags: android

Tengo un `EditText` en la parte inferior que se oculta a la hora de presionarlo para poder escribir.
¿Cómo lo puedo hacer para ver a la vez el `EditText` y el teclado?

Comment: Te ayuda esta pregunta ?: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262414/android-keyboard-hides-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usando la propiededad **android:focusableInTouchMode** me funciono una vez que tuve un problema parecido a ti. Algo como esto:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true
        />
```

Y en tu manifest en el activity donde este el edit text pones:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".Activities.TuActivity"
            android:configChanges="uiMode"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" />
```